# pyQt QTableView select a noncontiguous set of rows

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I have a QTableView, which is created this way:

```
    self.preset_delegate = PresetDelegate() # used to provide a combobox for making a selection from a set of options, column 0
    self.model_filelist = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.model_filelist.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HEADER_LABELS)
    self.list_filelist = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.list_filelist.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode( QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive )
    self.list_filelist.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.preset_delegate )
    self.list_filelist.setModel( self.model_filelist )
    self.list_filelist.setSelectionMode( QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection )
```

When the user presses a button, I would like to algorithmically select rows from the table.  The selection will not be contiguous.  For the purpose of our discussion, it could be any random subset of rows in the model/table.

This is pseudo-code for what I'm using to make the selection:

```
    files = [str(self.model_filelist.data( self.model_filelist.index(x,1)).toString()) for x in range(self.model_filelist.rowCount())]
    self.list_filelist.clearSelection()
    for x in match_set:
       match_index = files.index( x )
       model_index = self.model_filelist.index(match_index,1) # first column is okay
       self.list_filelist.selectionModel().select( model_index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select | QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Current )
```

My problem is the with selection model flag on the very last line.  Whether I use SelectCurrent, ToggleCurrent or Select | Current, or Toggle | Current, I only get the last item in my match_set remaining selected at the end of the loop.  As the loop executes, the selection is *changed* from one item to the other, rather than adding the new row to the set of the selection.  I hope that makes sense.

I thought for sure that SelectCurrent flag was the way to do this, but it's not working for me.  Any suggestions?  (python 2.6.7, Fedora 14, Qt4.4??? I can't be sure)

Comment: I don't think I've ever gone 18 hours with nobody having a suggestion.  I restructured the code to use the select() function that takes a QItemSelection, and I load the ItemSelection with a set of ItemSelectionRange objects that wrap the model indexes that interest me.  This seems to work.

Comment: If you've come up with a solution, you are allowed to answer your own question, and accept it. Encouraged even, there is a badge for doing so!

Comment: @Lego, okay, I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments to the question.  I did not solve why the original code failed, but I found this to work:

Use the version of select() that takes a QItemSelection object, and load that object with QItemSelectRange objects that wrap ModelIndex to the rows I'm interested in.